# Can anyone identify this tall vine that has volunteered in our back yard?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What is this 5-foot tall vine in Kentucky? It volunteered in our back yard.

[image: What is this 5-foot tall vine in Kentucky? It volunteered in our back yard.]

Comment: The species with the dark triangular leaves is also a vine - I reckon you are aiming at the plant with the lighter rounded leaves in the middle of the image? If yes, it's a bummer the leaves in close-up are out of focus.

Comment: @AliceD the dark triangular one is hedera helix.

Comment: Or are you aiming for the heart-shaped one on the top left? Perhaps you could provide a close-up image of a leaf and add an arrow in the existing figure to point out the species in question?

Comment: @AliceD: I'm sure they mean the plant most featured in the photo (having palmate leaf veining or patterning).  The leaves towards the bottom of the image are largely in focus.

Comment: @mgkrebbs — Is that generally used in the US or is it regional? Never heard it when I lived in Chicago and it is not British usage.

Comment: The term "volunteer" is used a lot here in Indiana USA, as in "It came up volunteer" to refer to a plant that just appeared.

Comment: @David https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteer_(botany) - I admit myself I have never heard it as a verb in this context (though the wiki page does make reference to the verb form), but rather as an adjective or noun.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is in the genus *Dioscorea* which is a wild yam.  There are several species native to the Eastern US.  A common species is [*Dioscorea villosa*](https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=divi4) but you will have to look up details and compare to your specimen.